# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel

http://localhost/laravel.dev/auth/login> bringsup error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Route.php

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'); 
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');       
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout'); // Registration routes... 
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');     
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');  
Route::controllers([ 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController', ]);
```

Comment: You need to add a lot of more information here so we can help you. Check the [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: my route.php loolike

Comment: Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');


Route::controllers([
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Comment: Any error on my route.php

Comment: No, just in your question.

Comment: Sorry i aam new to laravel i create route for login and i create view as well but when i type http://localhost/laravel.dev/auth/login it shows error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Answer (score 0):

It might sound funny but today I had the same problem and posted a question until i did migration `php artisan migrate` and realized it was working. Try migration it might help