# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am working with laravel 5. At first I defined a route as follows :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo "entered here.";
}
);
```

When I access it with  **http://localhost:8383/onboardadmin3/public/** It works fine. But when I change the route as follows :

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    echo "entered here.";
}
);
```

and try to access it with **http://localhost:8383/onboardadmin3/public/test** , I get the following error :

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

I have read the stack overflow solutions from the following links but none helped :

1. [Laravel 5.1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060832/laravel-5-1-notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161)
2. [NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180531/notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186650/in-laravel-5-notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186650/in-laravel-5-notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess enabled with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Can you try to return the output instead of echoing?

Comment: I have changed echo to return "entered here". But, I am getting the same error.

Comment: And if you remove the / before /test, maybe this helps?

Comment: I have removed the / it according to your suggestion but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you try to use an controller to handle the request? Does that works?

php artisan make:controller TestController
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');

TestController.php
class TestController extends Controller {
public function index() {
return 'hi';
}
}

Comment: It did not worked :(

Comment: Your asking a really hard question... Which version of laravel are you using? Laravel 5, 5.1 or 5.2?

Comment: It is really frustating for me. I have two other laravel projects running in this machine. They are working correctly. But here I am getting this error. My version is  5.1.34.

Comment: Did you do a lot of stuff in the new project or are you just at the start of your project?

Comment: I have just started it yesterday.

Comment: Is there an possibility to composer update your project or otherwise try to use laravel 5.2?

Comment: Found it at last. The domain was incorrect. It should be OnboardAdmin3. I do not know why the first link worked. However thanks for your help.